# Emit empty string event leads to an object?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm creating an event emitter related to an input text:

```
<input
            type="text"
            id="foo"
            [formControl]="control"
            autocomplete="off"

        />
```

with:

```
@Output()
textChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

public readonly control = new FormControl({value:'', disabled: this.disabled}, Validators.required);
```

Initialized like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.control.valueChanges
         .pipe(
             filter(text => {
                 return text.length == 0 || text.length >= 2;
             }),
             debounceTime(300),
             distinctUntilChanged()
         )
         .subscribe(text => this.textChange.emit(text));
 }
```

Strangely, if the text is populated I get:

```
textChange: "foooo"
```

but, if empty, I get:

```
textChange: {name: "textChange", args: ""}
```

while I would expect only "".

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know binding to native stuff is not the best practice.
Use reactive forms. Check this example

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g7j7vc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g7j7vc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g7j7vc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The end result is the same, I still get an object but this is an interesting improvement can you please reference why it's better use the forms?

Comment: Hm, maybe I misunderstood something. How's it the same? With the forms solution when you clear input, i.e. make it "" the emitted event is "". It can be seen in UI or via console log. And the reactive forms solution has explicit types. It would not have compiled if event was something else than a string.

Comment: As for your question ragarding forms, using the reactive forms module is more advanced approach which is more flexible and much less messy than the native input bindings apprroach, especially when it comes to really complex business logic.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use reactive forms as its suggested in another answer. In that case you will have a better control what is happening (also testing is much easier). There you can specify init values for your input component, you can add custom sync/async validators and much more...

In your case here:

if you change :

```
inputChanged(event:any) {
    this.valueChanged.next(this.value);
  }
```

to this:

```
inputChanged(event:any) {
    this.valueChanged.next(event.target.value);
  }
```

It should work.

Comment: Doesn't work: it seems to have to do with EventEmitter itself